# ansible play_hosts template loop

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to use the `play_hosts` variable in an ansible template.

I'm trying to setup a master / slave domain setup for wildfly.

So I wish to loop over all hosts in the inventory group, without having to specify a group.

This is what I'm trying:

```
{%- for host in play_hosts %}
  {%- if  'master' in hostvars[host][ansible_hostname + '_alias'] %}
<remote protocol="remote" host="{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}" port="9999" />
  {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

I get the below error:

```
failed: [atllvjksap012d.hughestelematics.net] (item=host) => {"failed": true, "item": "host", "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string
```

Comment: The jinja syntax is {% ... %} not {%- ... %} jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates

Comment: are you sure about `ansible_hostname + '_alias'` variable name?

Comment: I am quite sure about ansible_hostname + '_alias' I've used this variable in other places.

Comment: Can you try to just print hostvars and see what it shows? Example: debug: var=hostvar

Answer (score 0):

Playbook:

```
---
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005760/ansible-play-hosts-template-loop

- name: so question 39005760 version 2
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: show debug
      debug: msg="target = {{ item }} default ipv4 = {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
      with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
    - name: make template
      template:
        src: q39005760v2.j2
        dest: /home/ansible/q39005760.txt
```

Template:

```
{{ play_hosts }}

{% for host in play_hosts %}
<remote protocol="remote" host="{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}" port="9999" />
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

> ```
> [ak@vm566970 stackoverflow]$ ansible-playbook -i hosts q39005760v2.yml
>
> PLAY [so question 39005760] ****************************************************
>
> TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
> ok: [server274.mydomain.tld]
>
> TASK [show debug] **************************************************************
> ok: [server274.mydomain.tld] => (item=server274.mydomain.tld) => {
>     "item": "server274.mydomain.tld",
>     "msg": "target = server274.mydomain.tld default ipv4 = 100.101.102.103"
> }
>
> TASK [make template] ***********************************************************
> ok: [server274.mydomain.tld]
>
> PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
> server274.mydomain.tld       : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
> ```

Sample file:

> ```
> q39005760.txt      [----]  0 L:[  1+ 0   1/  5] *(0   / 124b) 0045 0x02D  [*][X]
> [u'server274.mydomain.tld']
>
> <remote protocol="remote" host="100.101.102.103" port="9999" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in the following manner:

```
{%- for h in play_hosts %}
  {%- if 'master' in hostvars[h][h.split('.')[0] + '_alias'] %}
<remote protocol="remote" host="{{ hostvars[h]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}" port="9999" /> 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The trick was not to rely on `ansible_hostname` but on the iteration variable `h`.

Fortunately, it only took me two days to figure out.